# Using socket.io with rabbitmq

Tags: typescript, sockets, socket.io, rabbitmq

On the client side, I use the socket.io library, on the server side I plan to use rabbitmq as well, since rabbitmq gives a lot of control over messages. But I have no experience with this. I know that rabbimq has such an opportunity as: confirmation of the sent message, that is, if the server sent a message to the client, but the client did not receive it, then rabbitmq will wait until the connection with the client is restored, and then send the message again.

Client Side Code:

```
const socket = socketIo.connect(SERVER_URL)

socket.on('message', function(data) {
  console.log('message: ', data)
})
```

It would be great if you advise me some kind of guide or example for my case.
Or An example where rabbitmq is just used and a library other than socket.io

Comment: You can totally use rabbitmq (or any other broker) in both server side and client side. If you want your client gets the message after returning online then it should subscribe any broker (rabbitmq or hivemq-mqtt broker)

Comment: If you determined to user socket.io then you can also implement the logic in serverside. Every message sender (publisher) must send the message with his username and the destination username. On connection of each client  you should save it's unique socket id (generated by socketio) and username in a key-value pattern. Now when a new message comes you should check first whether the destination username exists or not in your key-value stores (say it is a javascript object). If exists then the user now online. If not then store the message in database to send it in future connection.

Comment: This article may help you:  https://riptutorial.com/socket-io/example/30273/example-server-side-code-for-handling-users